# When pushing to Heroku: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been stuck on this for a few hours and can't seem to get it working.

I am following a tutorial and I'm trying to push my app to Heroku.

My gemfile looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'


# Gems used only for assets and not required 
# in production environments by default. 
group :assets do 
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails'
 gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3' 
end 

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development, :test do 
 gem 'sqlite3'
 gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0' 
end 

group :production do 
 gem 'pg'
end
```

When I push to Heroku, I get this:

```
    Lisa:sample_app admin-lisa$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 81, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (68/68), done.
Writing objects: 100% (81/81), 17.36 KiB, done.
Total 81 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing i18n 0.6.9
       Installing rake 10.3.2
       Installing minitest 5.3.5
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing rack 1.5.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing polyglot 0.3.5
       Installing mime-types 1.25.1
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.7.0
       Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
       Installing execjs 2.2.1
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Installing json 1.8.1
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.1
       Installing sass 3.2.19
       Installing rack-test 0.6.2
       Installing coffee-script 2.2.0
       Installing treetop 1.4.15
       Installing uglifier 1.2.3
       Installing sprockets 2.11.0
       Installing activesupport 4.1.1
       Installing mail 2.5.4
       Installing actionview 4.1.1
       Installing activemodel 4.1.1
       Installing actionpack 4.1.1
       Installing activerecord 4.1.1
       Installing actionmailer 4.1.1
       Installing sprockets-rails 2.1.3
       Installing railties 4.1.1
       Installing jquery-rails 3.1.1
       Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
       Installing sass-rails 4.0.3
       Installing rails 4.1.1
       Installing pg 0.17.1
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (27.18s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'turbolinks'
       (in /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:106:in `resolve'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:146:in `require_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:217:in `process_require_directive'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:167:in `block in process_directives'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `each'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `process_directives'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:99:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_868a3914-b83c-496d-b715-75262204c9cf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:polar-wave-2691.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:polar-wave-2691.git'
```

And when I visit the Heroku site, it says: Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

So I checked my logs, which say:

```
Lisa:sample_app admin-lisa$ heroku logs
2014-06-27T00:07:21.685434+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by somebody.lisa@gmail.com
2014-06-27T00:07:21.685490+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by somebody.lisa@gmail.com
2014-06-27T00:07:29+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-06-27T00:07:33+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-06-27T00:07:40.377399+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=polar-wave-2691.herokuapp.com request_id=5b29dca1-29e3-4410-8efb-99c74f1b14ec fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-27T00:07:40.673553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=polar-wave-2691.herokuapp.com request_id=39df86cb-8d9c-418f-afb9-8242fc5f311e fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-27T00:08:03.130094+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate` by somebody.lisa@gmail.com
2014-06-27T00:08:04.869272+00:00 heroku[run.1405]: State changed from starting to up
2014-06-27T00:08:06.629224+00:00 heroku[run.1405]: State changed from up to complete
2014-06-27T00:08:04.809756+00:00 heroku[run.1405]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate`
2014-06-27T00:08:06.612075+00:00 heroku[run.1405]: Process exited with status 1
2014-06-27T00:08:04.774227+00:00 heroku[run.1405]: Awaiting client
2014-06-27T00:08:10.068439+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=polar-wave-2691.herokuapp.com request_id=a6c649ff-2b4b-4a67-9bfa-c2e06b623c8a fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-27T00:08:10.354925+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=polar-wave-2691.herokuapp.com request_id=60a03227-4cfa-4ba3-b2e5-f84b63b0db07 fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-27T00:08:13.488700+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=polar-wave-2691.herokuapp.com request_id=21eb1930-2b7e-4e57-b0df-3fffaeffae29 fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-27T00:08:13.851121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=polar-wave-2691.herokuapp.com request_id=9b015c1f-e710-4866-acba-0f215ea5938d fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-27T00:08:40.685450+00:00 heroku[run.2450]: Awaiting client
2014-06-27T00:08:40.746839+00:00 heroku[run.2450]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate`
2014-06-27T00:08:39.220494+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate` by jonsson.lisa@gmail.com
2014-06-27T00:08:40.730443+00:00 heroku[run.2450]: State changed from starting to up
2014-06-27T00:08:42.454908+00:00 heroku[run.2450]: State changed from up to complete
2014-06-27T00:08:42.363758+00:00 heroku[run.2450]: Process exited with status 1
2014-06-27T00:08:55.126228
+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=polar-wave-2691.herokuapp.com request_id=5f1ec80d-7dc1-4810-91a1-1f61b7f1dc66 fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-27T00:08:55.685930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=polar-wave-2691.herokuapp.com request_id=03a9fa47-7148-4a12-b7ec-ffe2100f4161 fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-27T00:16:47.224352+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=polar-wave-2691.herokuapp.com request_id=fccc625d-9bd2-4d2b-8d95-a51fe4d210eb fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-27T00:16:47.589404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=polar-wave-2691.herokuapp.com request_id=336a9fd4-47c7-4342-a7c2-3815eb0b84d3 fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-27T00:17:01+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-06-27T00:17:05+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-06-27T00:18:13+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-06-27T00:19:08+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-06-27T00:20:16+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-06-27T00:21:03+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-06-27T00:22:11+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-06-27T00:22:39+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-06-27T00:23:31+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-06-27T00:23:56+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-06-27T00:24:37+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-06-27T00:25:06+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-06-27T00:26:09+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-06-27T00:26:37+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-06-27T00:39:14+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-06-27T00:39:51+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
```

I don't understand what it's trying to tell me, exactly, but I tried to run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

also

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I also checked my git status and everything has been committed.

I tried deleting my gemfile.lock and running bundle again and rake db:migrate and committing it all over, but no luck.

I'm just learning Rails and the heroku log isn't totally making sense to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What does your application.js file look like? If you are using turbolinks get rid of it. Rails may be trying to precompile your assets for you and minify them, but that may be tripping you up. Also check out https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor, you may want to install this gem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My application.js did include turoblinks, so I tried getting rid of it, and I also added rails_12factor and ran bundle again and pushed it up to git and heroku, but it still does the same thing. Hm..

Answer (score 0):

In your gemfile try adding **gem 'rails_12factor'** to production. So the code should change from

```
...
group :production do 
  gem 'pg'
end
```

to

```
...
group :production do 
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

**Edit: Here is what my entire Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record 
# gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:         https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read      more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Deploying to Heroku
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I don't think I had the rails_12 factor gem in the right location before. I'm still having the same issue, but I think you probably resolved another issue for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this a few weeks ago when building my first rails app; I would go ahead and remove your sass-rails gem, along with the group assets do, re-bundle, and give it another shot.

Should look like this:

```
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
```

not

```
group :assets do 
  # Use SCSS for stylesheets
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3' 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the things that solved it for me (thanks @plondon, that was a good eye!)

Since I took out turbolinks from my Gemfile, I also had to make sure that my application.css/.js was not using it. I cleaned out both files.

I also deleted my Gemlock.file and bundle installed again.

Finally, after a force-push it went through, particularly because my application.js was using Turbolinks when I didn't have it installed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps:

1. Remove the `gem 'turbolinks'` line from your Gemfile.
2. Remove the `//= require turbolinks` from your app/assets/javascripts/application.js.
3. Remove the two `"data-turbolinks-track" => true` hash key/value pairs from your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

In your Gemfile

```
gem "foreman"
group :production, :staging do
  gem "rails_12factor"
  gem "rails_stdout_logging"
  gem "rails_serve_static_assets"
end
```

More details [remove turbolink](https://howilearnedrails.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/how-to-remove-turbolinks-from-rails-4/)